# How to open a view inside a view with CodeIgniter 4?

Tags: codeigniter-4

I am new with CodeIgniter 4. At CodeIgniter 3 we can use a view inside another view like this :

```
<head>
      <?php this->load->view("containers/head"); ?>
</head>
```

But same is not working with CodeIgniter 4 and I couldn't find it. Any suggestions?

Have a great day!

Answer (score 7):

Okay, for those who may search this, I used this and it worked.

```
<head>
      <?php echo view("containers/head"); ?>
</head>
```

Comment: Sometimes the simplest answers are the best.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you read the documentation.
[View Layouts in CI4](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/outgoing/view_layouts.html#view-layouts)

My view layout template **layout.php**

```
[...]
<head>
    <?= $this->renderSection('head')?>
</head>
[...]
```

My view

```
<?= $this->extend('layout') ?>
<?= $this->section('head') ?>
    <!-- Code in block <head> -->
<?= $this->endSection('') ?>
```

It may also be helpful: [View Parser in CI4](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/outgoing/view_parser.html#view-parser)

Comment: Reading CI4 documentation is a challenge for beginners. The docs dwell on subtleties and skip over the "obvious". Your answer is a little like that too.  Case in point here is the "obvious" fact (obvious after you know it) that the "view" isn't an object, but is mere HTML text that can be handed to php's echo function (or to <?=. equivalent) rather than "returned" for the framework to deobjectfy and render.